# How to restore default Windows XP Control Panel?

Tags: windows-xp, control-panel

I've accidentally switched my Windows XP Control Panel to "Classic Mode".  How can I restore this back to the original Windows XP default (without reinstalling, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://www.xp-tips.com/toggle-control-panel-view.html

> By default, the Windows XP Control Panel appears as a window in which
>   various options are divided into categories. This "Category View"
>   makes it easy for users to locate the specific set of options that
>   they wish to access.
>
> However, you may prefer the more traditional view of the Control Panel
>   in which the sets of options are represented by a series of icons.
>   This "Classic View" of the XP control panel is similar in appearance
>   to the control panel on earlier versions of Windows.
>
> You might also need to switch the control panel view to more easily
>   follow a set of instructions that you have been given. If the
>   instructions assume that the Control Panel is displayed in Classic
>   View, when it is displayed in Category View on your computer, the
>   instructions may appear confusing or erroneous. And of course the
>   opposite is equally true.
>
> Luckily, changing the view of the Windows XP Control panel is very
>   easy.
>
> To change views:
>
> - Click "Start" and then click "Control Panel". The Control Panel should open.
> - If the Control Panel is in Category View, click "Switch to Classic View" on the left of the window.
> - If the Control Panel is in Classic View, click "Switch to Category View" on the left of the window.
>
> You can use the "Switch to.." link to toggle the Control Panel view as
>   desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you have accidentally closed the view pane on the left hand side of Control Panel (i.e., you can't see the 'Switch to category view' button), you can get it back:

**Control Panel / Tools / Options / General** - select **'Show common tasks in folders'** and apply. Once you have the view pane back you can '**Switch to classic view**' or '**category view**' as you please.